# Firefox gives me a 'The connection to WS was interrupted while the page was loading.' when sending base64 image

Tags: javascript, firefox, websocket

Currently, we are attempting to send a base64 image through a WebSocket connection. When I do this on Edge or Chrome it seems to work without any issues. The use case here is that we are grabbing the data url of a canvas element.

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMahM.png)

```
this.ws_connection = new WebSocket(websocketServerCobrowse);

sendCanvasImage = function(element){    
   let payload = {};
   payload.replacementImg = true;
   payload.imgData = element.toDataURL();
   payload.id = element.id;
   this.ws_connection.send('sendCanvasImage', payload);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So found out the reason why this was happening. Since I am using JSON.stringify for sending WebSocket calls, if the call was too long, it disconnected. The WebSocket didn't crash at all the browser literally blocked the message from being sent and then closed the connection. Now I am checking for the length of the message, and if it goes over, I either remove the offending part that is making it too long, or I display a message that for the person indicating what is happening.